# Why is the interface IMsoErrorBars not registered as COM interface?

Tags: .net, com, ms-office

When using the ErrorBars property in Microsoft.Office.Core.IMsoSeries using COM automation, I get a COM exception "Interface not registered" while it works fine using the property within an add-in.

I noticed that the interface IMsoErrorBars is not registered in Windows Registry like all other Office API interfaces are (or at least the ones if have been using so far). I checked several machines with Office 2010 or 2013 installed and they all missed the IID `{000C1721-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface`.

Does anybody know why it's missing?

**UDPATE**

Here's as example in C# ...

```
IEnumerable<int> ErrorBarsColors(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape)
{
    var seriesCollection = shape.Chart.SeriesCollection() as IEnumerable;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Core.IMsoSeries series in seriesCollection)
    {
        if (series.HasErrorBars)
        {
            var errorBars = series.ErrorBars;
            yield return errorBars.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB;
        }
    }
}
```

... that fails with the mentioned COM exception at the series.ErrorBars access when it's called in a stand-alone application using some code like this:

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
var presentation = application.Presentations.Open(SOME_PRESENTATION);
var shape = presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[1];
var colors = ErrorBarsColors(shape);
```

But the same code works perfectly when using it in a PowerPoint Add-In.

Meanwhile I found some other interfaces that neither are registered and show the same behavior.

Comment: Can you share the code that's failing?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the interfaces are not registered makes them unable to work for calls across apartments (the COM objects could use custom marshaling, but in this case, it seems they don't).  It works when you use it as an add-in because it's running in the same apartment (at least, that's my wild guess).

You may want to register the interfaces yourself in `HKCR\Interface\{IID}` with key `ProxyStubClsid32` having a default value of `{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` (the universal marshaler that looks up for the interface definition in a typelib) and the key `TypeLib` having a default value of `{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}` and a `Version` value with the installed Office typelib version, such as [2.3 for 2003, 2.4 for 2007, 2.5 for 2010, 2.6 and 2.7 for Office 2013](http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=528) (look for point 8).  It shouldn't matter which, the interface should remain the same between versions.

But that doesn't make it right, the underlying operations may require some sort of same-apartment, hence in-process, data access.  With a separate process, you may be violating both assumptions.  It's better to contact Microsoft and ask if this is a bug or an unintended omission.  Or just try it out, with the risk of falling prey to the "it works on my machine" phenomenon.

The sure way around is to have the Office application create an object to which you can dispatch calls to the `ErrorBars` property given a `Series` object.  Maybe have an add-in for it, since you've already tried and it worked.

Comment: That sounds like a good explanation... And contacting Microsoft is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not all COM interfaces are registered.  Only COM interfaces that can be directly created via `CoCreateInstance` have to be registered.  If the COM interface is obtained from some other method (in this case, from the ErrorBars property), it does not have to be registered.

Comment: Registering an interface has very little to do with `CoCreateInstance`, only because you can tell it to (tell the factory to) `QueryInterface` the created object for you.  So, it's about marshaling, and it's necessary to register interfaces for calls to work across process boundaries, even if the COM object provides custom marshaling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mandatory registration for COM interfaces. Those mentioned in registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{CLSID}` are typically interfaces that either require/use custom proxy/stub handlers, or registered along with registration of type library which contains them.

Comment: But if the interface is not registered, the COM object must implement custom marshaling.  Also, calls on such interface will not work across process boundaries.

Comment: This is almost true, except "must". Not every interface is marshaled at all. Then PS pairs are relatively easy to build, so it is not something extremely rare.

Comment: You're right, "must" is a very strong word.  What I meant is that marshaling is needed for an object or its interface pointers to cross apartments, and an interface must be registered for it to cross processes.  Otherwise, the COM API returns error codes, and higher-level libraries/managed environments usually throw exceptions.